# searching strings with one missmatch by grepl

Tags: r, bioinformatics, grepl

I would like to search for substrings in another string. The output has to be a logical, that is why i was assuming `grepl()` would be the best option.

The requirements are, that the the function has to detect both strings which patterns fit exactly (String 2 & 3) and at least one missmatch is allowed (String 1 & 3)
An example would look like this:

String1: ABCDEFGHIJKL

String2: ABDEFGHIJKL

String3: ABDEFG

Meaning the function has to detect both String 1 and String 2 when String 3 is the searched pattern.

Another option would be the `matchpattern()` function of the Biostrings package. But here, the output is not an logical but an:

`Formal class 'XStringViews' [package "Biostrings"] with 5 slots`

The option to transform this into a logical would be working aswell.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe try the `?agrepl` function

Comment: Thanks a lot. The answer is , agrepl(String3,c(String2,String1), max.distance=list(substitutions=1))

Answer (score 2):

```
library(stringr)
stri <- c("ABCDEFG", "ABCDEFGHGT", "ABFCDE", "saffaf")


str_match <- function(pattern, st_c) {
      logic_f <- NULL
      for (i in seq_along(st_c)){
        var <- strsplit(st_c[i], "")[[1]]
        det <- str_detect(pattern, var)
        logic <- ifelse(TRUE %in% det, TRUE, FALSE)
        logic_f <- append(logic_f, logic)
      }
      return(logic_f)
}


str_match("ABD", stri)
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: hm, that was not what i meant, i want to detect c("ABCDEF", "ABCDEFG") with "ABD"

Comment: @Don Castanio, I editted the answer, it is a function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is also helpful :)

Comment: @DonCastanio, if it solved your issue, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Purely for fun and not sure if viable for longer strings:

```
S1<-"ABCDEFGHIJKL"

S2<-"ABDEFGHIJKL"

S3<-"ABDEFG"

find_partial_matching_string<-function(string, pattern){
  
  require(stringr)
  
  a<-vector()
  b<-vector()
  
  for (i in 1:nchar(string)){
    
    x<-str_sub(string, i, i)
    a<-c(a,x)
  }
  
  for(j in  1:nchar(pattern)){
    
    y<-str_sub(pattern, j, j)
    b<-c(b,y)
  }
  
  z <- a %in% b
 
  if(table(z[1:length(b)])<=1){
    return(string)     
  }
}

> find_partial_matching_string(string = S1, pattern = S3)
[1] "ABCDEFGHIJKL"
> find_partial_matching_string(string = S2, pattern = S3)
[1] "ABDEFGHIJKL"
```

Comment: @Don Castanio, this was your questions' answer??! Yes what @MrFlick said about `agrepl` is definitly true short answer, and my answer is based on `stringr` package with same results as `agrepl` function. But accepting this answer is so weired.

Comment: @Killbill i actually agree with you. if @ MrFlick put(s) his comment into an answer, i'd strongly suggest awarding him the points. 
That being said, calling (the acceptance of) my answer weird while basically giving the same answer is a little weird in itself.

Comment: So the answer i used was the one of MrFlick, since he could not be awarded since his answer is a comment, i tried to award at least someone. SO in this case who is going to get the right answer points

Comment: @Don Castanio No one. It is nice of you to think that way and i encourage you to reward points for attempts at helping (as you did) but if the answer is from a comment then upvoting the comment (as you also did i assume) will have to do :) - you can ofc always ask the commenter to put his/her comment into an answer to reward the points.